# Custom 'Number' class — can it be made to work in place of 'float' or other built-in type?

Tags: c++, lua, c++14

I am writing a class with various operator overloading which should be a drop-in replacement for `float` (or similar) in some "external" code.
In particular, there are 3 example usages which I'd like to support (see below), and I can't find a way to define my class in a way that satisfies all 3.

Is it possible?

*Aside:* In truth, I'm trying to implement a custom `lua_Number` type in Lua 5.3, which is typically either `float` or `double`. I am compiling Lua as C++, and trying to use a fixed-point representation instead. While it is true that I can alter the "external" code (since it's just embedded Lua), I would very much rather not (:

Live code link, if you want to play around: https://godbolt.org/z/37c6nj

Here are the 3 use cases I need to support:

**Example 1:** simple usage where MyNum is a union member.
This means I cannot have exotic copy constructors and such, since "non-trivial" versions of those would cause the union to be ill-formed (without modification).

```
SomeUnion x;
x.num = 123.0f;
SomeUnion y = x;
```

**Example 2:** MyNum is a member of a union (as above), and that union is the member of a struct. I'm not sure exactly how this is different from the first example, b ut it is the final sticking point in my current version of the code. This is the bit that doesn't currently compile in the linked example.

```
SomeStruct s1;
s1.u.num = x.num;
SomeStruct s2;
// With all the code as-is, this is the line that fails:
//   error: use of deleted function 'SomeStruct& SomeStruct::operator=(const SomeStruct&)'
//   note: 'SomeStruct& SomeStruct::operator=(const SomeStruct&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
s2 = s1;
```

**Example 3:** Usage concerning `volatile`. This requires a custom `operator=`.

```
volatile SomeUnion v;
// If we don't have a custom operator= with 'volatile' qualifier, we get:
// ERROR: passing 'volatile MyNum' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
v.num = x.num;
```

If I remove the `volatile` implementation of `operator=`, then Example1 and Example2 compile, but Example3 does not.

If I include the `volatile` version of `operator=`, then Example1 and Example3 compile, but Example2 does not.

Is there some way to make them all work?

Or, failing that, any ideas for a "minimally invasive" set of changes to the external code to allow it to work?

Comment: Could [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio) be of help for an implementation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't understand your comment — maybe it was meant for a different question?

Comment: "*I'm trying to implement a custom `lua_Number` type in Lua 5.3*" That's not going to work. `lua_Number` *must* be a built-in type. The Lua codebase can't handle anything user-defined, since that's not how C works.

Comment: @jwd No, it was for this one. You said you want to implement exact fractions instead of FP intrinsics, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas why must it? For instance, PICO-8 uses a fixed-point implementation of Number in its Lua interpreter. Here's an open-source clone [luaconf.h](https://github.com/samhocevar/z8lua/blob/9e7a69cda843012ff766407f924c9028e5a37852/luaconf.h#L574) [z8::fix32 impl](https://github.com/samhocevar/z8lua/blob/9e7a69cda843012ff766407f924c9028e5a37852/fix32.h#L23). That's Lua 5.2; I'm trying to do similar in 5.3.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: no, I am trying to implement a drop-in replacement for `float` to be used in some external code (Lua, in this case). Whether it is fractions for fixed-point or anything else is an implementation detail, not the issue I'm struggling with. I'm trying to get the given example code to *compile*.

Comment: @jwd: PICO-8, from what I can tell, is a *modified* Lua interpreter. If you can change Lua's source code, you can do anything you want. But you're explicitly trying *not* to do that.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I should have said (edited to add): I am compiling Lua as C++. So, I have the operator overloading universe available to me, which does not require Lua modification. In fact, the compile error detailed in this question seems to be the very last thing in my way. Also, while I am trying to avoid modifying Lua, it is not strictly verboten, so I"m interested in small-blast-radius suggestions, too (see end of question).

Comment: @NicolBolas: also also (:  I'm fine with "modifying lua" insofar as I'm changing `luaconf.h`, and other bits that are "friendly to modification." I'm just trying not to do too much deep brain-surgery on the core codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to define that union which is needed for interoperability as:

```
union SomeUnion {
    uint32_t num;
    void * pFoo;

    void set(const MyNum& myNum) {
        num = *reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(&myNum);
    }

    MyNum get() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<MyNum*>(&this->num);
    }
};
```

MyNum copies should be simply default:

```
MyNum(const MyNum& other) = default;
MyNum& operator=(const MyNum& other) = default;
```

This union is perfect for any low-level operations like `volatile` since it involves only primitive types; on the other hand it is easy to use the `num` field as a storage for a `MyNum` object using the getter and setter methods.